# Unable to invoke recursively the function using settimeout in javascript

Tags: javascript

Below is my javascript code. I am trying to get my function timedisplay() triggered each second. 
But it is not hapenning so..

```js
function timedisplay() {
  alert ("Welcome");
  var pelement = document.getElementById("myclock");
  var timeobj = new Date();
  alert (timeobj);
  pelement.innerHTML = timeobj.toLocaleTimeString();
  alert (pelement.toLocaleTimeString());
  settimeout (timedisplay,1000);
}
```

```html
Timer Clock Testing..
<button onclick="timedisplay()">Click me</button> 
<p id="myclock"></p>
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: Note that you have a typo; it should be "Timer Clock".

Comment: I tried inside body, still same problem.

Comment: You might want to spell `settimeout` correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pelement element does not have  toLocaleTimeString() function, it references element `myclock`
settimeout should go setTimeout

Otherwise your javascript is fine:

```
  alert (pelement.toLocaleTimeString());
```

```js
function timedisplay()
{
 //alert ("Welcome");
 var pelement = document.getElementById("myclock");
 var timeobj = new Date();
//alert (timeobj);
pelement.innerHTML = timeobj.toLocaleTimeString();
//alert (pelement.toLocaleTimeString());
setTimeout (timedisplay,1000);

}
```

```html
   Timer Cock Testing..
    <button onclick="timedisplay()">Click me</button> 
    <p id="myclock">
    </p>
```

Comment: This would be more helpful with an explanation.

Comment: @EdCottrell Explanation is on the way

Comment: I tried the same, but it works in this "run code snippet", but it doesn't work in the browser. :(

Comment: @user3796318 There may be other javascript error in your code else where, please check your console and share for furhter help

Comment: Thanks, it is working now. typo mistake.

Answer (score 5):

You might consider calling the `setInterval` function rather than,`setTimeout`, and you only need to call it once. While *technically* permissible for `setInterval` to be in your callback , it's much better to put it in a separate function, as follows:

```
/* the callback */
function refreshTime() {
    var pelement = document.getElementById("myclock");
    var timeobj = new Date();
    pelement.innerHTML = timeobj.toLocaleTimeString();
}

/* start the clock */
function timedisplay() {
    setInterval( refreshTime, 1000 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters, it's `setTimeout`, not `settimeout` - the capitalization matters.

Second, don't do it with recursion; there's almost no reason you want recursive timeouts like this. To make it repeat, use `setInterval` instead, and put it in the body or in another function.

That said, if you fix the typo in `setTimeout`, your code looks otherwise okay.

Comment: Do, we have any disadvantage using this recursive mechanism rather using setInterval ?. stack overflow issue something like that?

Comment: Yes; it's much easier to run into problems with recursion in this instance. It would be better to use `setInterval`, but only do so the first time the user clicks the button. Otherwise, you could end up with multiple recursions (based on multiple clicks), leading to a bad user experience or even crashes.